# Not able to load AMD modules through Jest

Tags: requirejs, amd, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest for unit testing my React code but I'm also using requirejs and so all my React code is in AMD modules. It obviously works well in browser but when I run Jest tests, it can't load my AMD modules.
Initially it was giving me error for define saying `define is not defined`, so I used amdefine by Requirejs to fix it. Now it can understand `define` but still can't load my module.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and here is what I've done :

[**Module.js**](https://github.com/1twitif/testRequireJSAmdModulesWithJest/blob/gh-pages/module.js)

```js
(()=> {
    const dependencies = ['./dep.js'];
    const libEnv = function (dep) {

        // lib content
        function theAnswer (){
            return dep.answer;
        }

        return {theAnswer}; // exports

    };
    //AMD & CommonJS compatibility stuff
    // CommonJS
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof require !== 'undefined'){
        module.exports = libEnv.apply(this, dependencies.map(require));
        module.exports.mockable = libEnv; // module loader with mockable dependencies
    }
    // AMD
    if (typeof define !== 'undefined') define(dependencies, libEnv);
})();
```

You will found all needed files on [my github repository](https://github.com/1twitif/testRequireJSAmdModulesWithJest) to test :

- in browser for requirejs
- with node for jest

https://github.com/1twitif/testRequireJSAmdModulesWithJest

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem, so I went ahead and mocked my dependency at the top of test file:

```
jest.mock('../../components/my-button', () => {
  // mock implementation
})

import MyButton from '../../components/my-button';
```

This way, when MyButton is loaded, its dependency is already mocked, so it won't try to load the RequireJS module.

Answer (score 1):

There's no official Facebook support for requirejs in Jest yet. But's planned. Look this thread:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/17

Also in this thread Sterpe posted a plugin he wrote to do it (but I didn't try it):
https://github.com/sterpe/jest-requirejs

Comment: Can you add some information to your answer about the solution in addition to the links please?

Comment: @Dani, this might work, let me try it and get back here. Btw, I also tried using amdrequire plugin for it, which apparently is exactly what I was looking for. But it works perfectly in any node file except when you're running it through Jest file. Weird that Jest somehow changes the global scope or some other scope because of which it doesn't work